# Old Man's interaction with Mulder "10 years ago"?

Tags: the-x-files

I can't find a source to quote or a clip to post, but in the first episode of the new X-Files miniseries, Mulder and the Old Man (Rance Howard) have a conversation outside at night. Mulder says, at one point:

> Ten years ago, you came to me saying you couldn't take your secrets to
>   your grave, that you couldn't live with it.

**Is this incident Mulder refers to from ten years ago a previously established event? Or is it new to the story?**

Comment: Wondering now if it would be prudent to suggest a "the-x-files-2016" tag?

Comment: @Dpeif My opinion is not to add a 2016 tag because the show is being advertised as "Season 10" by Fox. IMDb does have it listed as a new show but this is incorrect. I guess it could later be repackaged and marketed as a mini series but I think they are keeping options open for now.

Comment: @sanpaco A minor quibble - I have not seen Fox advertise it as "Season 10", I've only seen some articles do that.  "Season 10" is actually a comic book series that was endorsed by Chris Carter.

Comment: Go to fox.com and you will see the current episodes listed as S10 E01 and S10 E02.

Comment: I'm also familiar with the season 10 comics and own and have read them. No mention of the Old Man in them either.

Comment: Congratulations, this question is the winner of the [corresponding topic challenge](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/2112/49).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is new to the story. There hasn't been any official X-Files canon since the show's cancelation in 2002 which was 14 years ago. If they met 10 years ago then that would have occurred in 2006 which was before the move I Want To Believe (2008), but no mention was made of the character in that movie.

I could expound on my personal theories of who the Old Man is and where he came from but I won't. It is unfortunate that he is not set to reappear in the rest of the episodes. Hopefully if the show continues or if a movie is made there will be some more information about him and his background.

Comment: Thanks for the research into the comics, good answer. I also agree about the tag, I see what you mean.